# julia implement convert for struct containing NTuple

Tags: methods, types, julia

I'm trying to implement a `convert` for struct containing `NTuple`:

```
import Base: convert

abstract type AbstractMyType{N, T} end

struct MyType1{N, T} <: AbstractMyType{N, T}
    data::NTuple{T, N}
end

struct MyType2{N, T} <: AbstractMyType{N, T}
    data::NTuple{T, N}
end

foo(::Type{MyType2}, x::AbstractMyType{N, T}) where {N, T} = x
convert(::Type{MyType2}, x::AbstractMyType{N, T}) where {N, T} = MyType2{T}(x.data)

println(foo(MyType2, MyType1((1,2,3))))         # MyType1{Int64,3}((1, 2, 3))
println(convert(MyType2, MyType1((1,2,3))))     # MethodError
```

Defined functions `foo` and `convert` have the same signature. For some reason function `foo` returns normally while `convert` throws `MethodError`. Why Julia cannot find my `convert` method?

*julia version 1.4.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia *is* finding your convert method:

```
julia> println(convert(MyType2, MyType1((1,2,3))))     # MethodError
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching MyType2{3,T} where T(::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64})
Stacktrace:
 [1] convert(::Type{MyType2}, ::MyType1{Int64,3}) at ./REPL[16]:1
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[18]:1
```

That stack trace is saying that it's inside your `convert` function (in my case, I defined it on the first line of the 16th REPL prompt).  The problem is that it cannot find a `MyType2{T}(::Tuple)` constructor.

Julia automatically creates a number of constructors for you when you don't use an inner constructor; in this case you can either call `MyType(())` or `MyType{T, N}(())`, but Julia doesn't know what to do with only one type parameter passed (by default):

```
julia> MyType2((1,2,3))
MyType2{Int64,3}((1, 2, 3))

julia> MyType2{Int, 3}((1,2,3))
MyType2{Int64,3}((1, 2, 3))

julia> MyType2{Int}((1,2,3))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching MyType2{Int64,T} where T(::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64})
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[7]:1
 [2] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:331
 [3] eval_user_input(::Any, ::REPL.REPLBackend) at /Users/mbauman/Julia/release-1.4/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/REPL/src/REPL.jl:86
 [4] run_backend(::REPL.REPLBackend) at /Users/mbauman/.julia/packages/Revise/AMRie/src/Revise.jl:1023
 [5] top-level scope at none:0
```

So the fix is either to define that method yourself, or change the body of your convert method to call `MyType{T,N}` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Just define the method

```
convert(::Type{MyType2}, x::AbstractMyType{N, T}) where {N, T} = MyType2(x.data)
```

Testing:

```
julia> convert(MyType2, MyType1((1,2,3)))
MyType2{Int64,3}((1, 2, 3))
```